# Tool or better program design to manage session keys

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a laravel website, which contains multi-page forms, so there are many session keys set and get in my code, and it's hard to track and maintain.

For example:

```php
// there are many keys in middlewares, livewire components, requests, tests, etc.
session('trip');
session('route');
session('hotel');
session('traffic');
session('restaurant');
session('agreement');

//some stores multidimensional array, so there are keys like this:
session('trip.days.luggage');
session('route.maps');
session('hotel.days.room.special_request');
session('traffic.airplane.departure.delays');
session('restaurant.days.dinner.main_course.meat');
session('agreement.insurance.reciprocal_healthcare');
```

I've tried to use config, so I can easily to see all keys that has been used:

```php
// config/session-keys.php
return [
    'trip' => 'trip',
    'trip_days_luggage' => 'trip.days.luggage',
    'route' => 'route',
    'route_maps' => 'route.maps',
    'hotel' => 'hotel',
    'hotel_days_room_has_booked' => 'hotel.days.room.has_booked'
    'hotel_days_room_special_request' => 'hotel.days.room.special_request'
    // etc
];
```

So I use this in my code:

```php
//get session
session(config('session-keys.trip'));
session(config('session-keys.trip_days_luggage'));
session(config('session-keys.route'));
session(config('session-keys.route_maps'));
session(config('session-keys.hotel'));
session(config('session-keys.hotel_days_room_has_booked'));
session(config('session-keys.hotel_days_room_special_request'));

//set session
session([config('session-keys.trip') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.trip_days_luggage') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.route') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.route_maps') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.hotel') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.hotel_days_room_has_booked') => $value]);
session([config('session-keys.hotel_days_room_special_request') => $value]);
```

then I wrote helpers:

```php
// app/helpers.php
if (!function_exists('get_session')) {
    function get_session($key)
    {
        return session(config('session-keys.' . $key));
    }
}

if (!function_exists('set_session')) {
    function set_session($key, $value)
    {
        return session([config('session-keys.' . $key) => $value]);
    }
}
```

so it became like this:

```php
//get session
get_session('trip');
get_session('trip_days_luggage');
get_session('route');
get_session('route_maps');
get_session('hotel');
get_session('hotel_days_room_has_booked');
get_session('hotel_days_room_special_request');

//set session
set_session('trip', $value);
set_session('trip_days_luggage', $value);
set_session('route', $value);
set_session('route_maps', $value);
set_session('hotel', $value);
set_session('hotel_days_room_has_booked', $value);
set_session('hotel_days_room_special_request', $value);
```

But it doesn't look good and maybe there are hidden problems.

If there is a tool to parse every `session()` in my code and look for keys, and use a command like `php artisan session-key:list` to show all keys. Or a better program design. Please share any ideas, thank you!

---

Below is a much simpler example of how I store session data, mostly form data, some retrieved from the database, and I try to make it as simple as possible.

Let's say a user fills an agreement, and then submit to fill the hotel form, and then submit to fill the traffic form, and then submit to see the preview page.

Before submitting, he can go backward to any form to change the input value.

```php
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/agreement', \App\Http\Livewire\Agreement::class);
Route::get('/hotel', \App\Http\Livewire\Hotel::class);
Route::get('/traffic', \App\Http\Livewire\Traffic::class);
Route::get('/preview', \App\Http\Livewire\Preview::class)->middleware('requireSessionData');
Route::get('/thank-you-page', function () {
    return view('thank-you-page');
});
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class requireSessionData
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (
            !session()->has('agreement')
            ||
            !session()->has('hotel')
            ||
            !session()->has('traffic')
        ) {
            abort(419);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Agreement extends Component
{
    public $reciprocal_healthcare;

    public $email;

    public function mount()
    {
        if(auth()->check()){
            $this->email = auth()->user()->email;
        }

        if(session()->has('agreement')){
            $this->reciprocal_healthcare = session('agreement.reciprocal_healthcare');
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.agreement');
    }

    public function saveAgreement()
    {
        $this->validate();
        session(['agreement' => (array) get_object_vars($this)]);
        return redirect('/hotel');
    }
}
```

```php
{{-- resources/views/livewire/agreement.blade.php --}}
<input type="checkbox" name="reciprocal_healthcare" value="1" wire:model="reciprocal_healthcare">

@if(auth()->check())
    {{ auth()->user->email }}
@else
    <input type="text" name="email" wire:model="email">
@endif

<button type="button" wire:click="saveAgreement">Save Agreement</button>
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Hotel extends Component
{
    public $special_request;

    public function mount()
    {
        if(session()->has('hotel')){
            $this->special_request = session('hotel.special_request');
        }elseif(auth()->check()){
            $this->special_request = auth()->user()->special_request;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hotel');
    }

    public function saveHotel()
    {
        $this->validate();
        session(['hotel' => (array) get_object_vars($this)]);
        return redirect('/traffic');
    }
}
```

```php
{{-- resources/views/livewire/hotel.blade.php --}}
<input type="text" name="special_request" wire:model="special_request">
<button type="button" wire:click="saveHotel">Save Hotel</button>
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Traffic extends Component
{
    public $airplane;

    public function mount()
    {
        if(session()->has('traffic')){
            $this->airplane= session('traffic.airplane');
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.traffic');
    }

    public function saveTraffic()
    {
        $this->validate();
        session(['traffic' => (array) get_object_vars($this)]);
        return redirect('/preview');
    }
}
```

```php
{{-- resources/views/livewire/traffic.blade.php --}}
<div x-data="{ airplane: @entangle('airplane') }">
    <input type="text" name="airplane" x-init="get-airplane-data-from-javascript-library" 
 wire:model="airplane">
</div>
<button type="button" wire:click="saveTraffic">Save Traffic</button>
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Preview extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.preview');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        if(auth()->check()){
            $user = auth()->user();
        }else{
            $user = User::create(['email' => session('agreement.email')]);
        }

        $user->agreement()->create(session('agreement'));
        $user->hotel()->create(session('hotel'));
        $user->traffic()->create(session('traffic'));

        return redirect('/thank-you-page');
    }
}
```

```php
{{-- resources/views/livewire/preview.blade.php --}}

@foreach(session('agreement') as $agreement)
    <div>{{ $agreement }}</div>
@endforeach

@foreach(session('hotel') as $hotel)
    <div>{{ $hotel }}</div>
@endforeach

@foreach(session('traffic') as $traffic)
    <div>{{ $traffic }}</div>
@endforeach
<button type="button" wire:click="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `get_session` misses an `.` here `'session-keys' . $key`

Comment: What’s the point I’m missing here about using all these session keys?

Comment: @dbf Session keeps form data for client change and preview before form submit. Normally it is fine, like a simple contact us form, or a registration form. But my project contains many multi-page forms, for example, if there is a 10 pages forms, and when a client fill the 6th form, he may decide to go back to the 3rd and the 5th form to change some input content. In the end, those session keys grows too many and become hard to track.

Comment: Yea got it. Don’t you think one single form object which gets serialized to session would be nicer and simpler to maintain? I mean PHP has a pretty strong support for OOP. Just guessing ..

Comment: @dbf Thanks for your advice. To use one single form object might face a similar issue as session. For example, if I use a hotel object and store it into the session, then I need to use `session('hotel')->days->room->has_booked` to get the value. I have no idea how to avoid this problem. And maybe, why don't I just develop a session key parser and upload to packagist, maybe  someone has the same problem.

Comment: Yea, you will come across different solutions to implement, just remember that a session is just another form of caching, where you have to ask yourself the question if a session is suitable for the solution. I’ve worked on quite some big projects and the direct use of session for temporary storage was extremely rare. Most of the time it’s just a link to a session where the session stores a cache key to access all information cached and both expire at the same time, where if a session expires, the data is gone, a cache might contain the info even after 1 week if needed ..

Comment: @dbf Thanks for your reply. I think the reason why I use session is mainly because the form requires the client to login to retrieve some user data before filling the form, and the form data is stored into the db only when the client submits and confirms he is going to do payment. I'll consider your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @Autodesk It‘s not quite clear to me what these session keys store, are those input values? Serialized form data? Something else? It would be good to see a form example where the form input reflects how it is saved in session. If you expand your question on the above I could write you an example on how my implementation would look like, comparing decisions against quality and quantity and what could make sense and what not.

Comment: @Autodesk In other words, a simple minimal use case would be great ;)

Comment: @dbf Sorry for the reply so late. I added an example, and I try to make it as simple as possible, I hope it is okay. Thank you!

Comment: @Autodesk No problem :) That’s the exact sample I needed, I’ll give it a thought and reply with an answer in the next few hours

Comment: @Autodesk what does the middleware `requireSessionData` do?

Comment: @dbf the middleware `requireSessionData` to check if the session has session('agreement'), session('hotel') and session('traffic'), then go to the preview page; otherwise abort. I added it below the route. Thank you!

Comment: Okidoki, I prepared something but I need a bit more time, will post it tonight and I’ll try to be as thorough as possible ;)

Comment: @dbf Thank you, no rush, I really appreciate you spending a lot of time to help! I hope one day I can provide some help, too.